# How to get value json in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

JSON : {"faktor":["sds"],"presentase":["23"]}

---

**Laravel Controller :**

```
public static function factor_task($id_project, $urutan)
    {
       
       return (DB::table('project_faktor')  ->select('faktor_presentase')
                                            ->where('id_project', '=', $id_project)
                                            ->where('urutan', '=', $urutan)
                                            ->get());
    }
```

**Blade View:**

```
$id_project = $projects->id_project;
$array_delay_factors = (json_decode(App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::factor_task('51', '1'),true));
$array_delay_factors_count = $array_delay_factors[0]['faktor_presentase'];
              
echo ($array_delay_factors_count->faktor);
```

But, it shows error like this
Trying to get property 'faktor' of non-object (0)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKpmT.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are you calling `json_decode` on the return from `factor_task`?

Comment: it shows error 
`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (0)`
when not use `json_decode`

Answer (score 0):

You have a Collection of `stdClass` objects returned from that method. If you just want the first object and that single value:

```
App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::factor_task('51', '1')
    ->first()
    ->faktor_presentase;
```

`faktor_presentase` is the only field you selected in that query in that Controller method. This also assumes there is at least 1 result returned.